# How to show column names in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a `SELECT` statement to show the list of fields in the table.

```
COLUMN

column_1
column_2
column_3
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tablename'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the information schema tables, particularly [`columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_schema = @schema_name and table_name = @table_name;
```

Note that this metadata is stored *per database*.  So if you want a table in another database, you need three part naming:

```
select column_name
from <database>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_schema = @schema_name and table_name = @table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet one more option:  This will return results on any **table**,**ad-hoc query** or even a **stored procedure**.

(using `spt_values` as a demonstration)

**Example**

```
Select column_ordinal
      ,name
      ,system_type_name 
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select * From master..spt_values',null,null )
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can also highlight the tablename in a query then press ALT+F1 to show the highlighted table info.

[image: Table Help Object]